# Is it possible to get a reference to a live collection in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple table with 1 row to start out with.

```
<table>
    <tr id="tr1">
        <td>ROW 1</td>
        <td>ROW 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Each `tr` listens to a click event. Once clicked on a table row I would like to get the number of rows in the table without having to constantly requery it. Does jQuery somewhere store the current collection of `tr's` and if so how can I access it?

```
$("table").on("click", "tr", function(e){

    $("#output").html("click on row with id " + $(this).attr("id") + "<br>")

        $("#output").append("Number of rows" + $("table").find("tr").size())
        // instead of "live" requerying $("table").find("tr") is there another way to get to all tr's

});

// more code...

$("table").append("<tr id='tr2'><td>ROW 2</td><td>ROW 2</td></tr>");
```

EDIT: To be clear, getting the number of rows is just an example. I actually need to perform other operations on the collection as well

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Flandre/Ed4pp/2/

Comment: If it is a dynamic table where you add rows/delete rows then you have to requery `$("table").find("tr").length` (note not size()). If not set that to a var outside the handler and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer **No**, There is no live query to maintain the length of the table.

Since it is a dynamic table where you add rows/delete rows then you have to requery

`$("table").find("tr").length //(note not size()).`

If not set that to a var outside the handler and update it when you add/delete rows.

```
var rowCount = $("table").find("tr").length;
$("table").on("click", "tr", function(e) {
    $("#output").html("click on row with id " + $(this).attr("id") + "<br>")
    $("#output").append("Number of rows" + rowCount);

});


function addRow() {
    // add a row to the table
    $("table").append("<tr id='tr2'><td>ROW 2</td><td>ROW 2</td></tr>");
    rowCount++; //Manually :P
}

addRow();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Ed4pp/4/)

Comment: The rowCount++ is a nice idea, however I used this example to provide a more simplified version of my problem. I need to perform additional things with the table cells.

Comment: @Andre You got 2 options, **1.** re-query - which you know how to do **2.** live manual update :P

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("table tr").on("click", function(e){
```

Instead of:

```
$("table").on("click", "tr", function(e){
```

And this:

```
$("#output").append("Number of rows" + $("table").find("tr").size())
```

Should be:

```
$("#output").append("Number of rows" + $("table tr").length)
```

Comment: How will that handle additional table rows that are added later?

Comment: the `on` function in jQuery is a live event, so when a new row is created it click function will be applied to the new row

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe jQuery keeps track of such things. When you use delegated event handlers, the only handler is placed on the selected element (`table`). When the user clicks a `tr`, the event bubbles up the DOM tree until it reaches `table`, where the event is handled.

If you want to keep that number of `tr`s up to date without polling, you might look into mutation events: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent

Here's a plugin, don't know if it's any good though: https://github.com/jollytoad/jquery.mutation-events

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/mkjkm/

```
var table = $("table")[0];
$(table).on("click", "tr", function(e) {

    $("#output").html("click on row with id " + this.id + "<br>")

    $("#output").append("Number of rows" + table.rows.length)
    $(table).append("<tr id='tr" + (table.rows.length + 1) + "'><td>ROW " + (table.rows.length + 1) + "</td><td>ROW " + (table.rows.length + 1) + "</td></tr>");
});
```

The DOM keeps a collection of all rows in a given table on the table's DOMElement.